# Get Array out of JSON-structure with tidyjson

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to read an array out of a JSON structure with tidyjson as I'm trying to fasten up my code.
My input data is of the structure

```
json <- "{\"key1\":\"test\",\"key2\":[\"abc\",\"def\"]}"
```

I want my output to be a data frame where key1 is one column and key2 is the second column in which all elements of the array are pasted together and separated by ";".

I tried something like

```
result <- json %>% spread_values(a = jstring("key1"), b = paste0(jstring("key2"), collapse = ";"))
```

I really have no idea how to get the array out of the JSON in the spread_values function.

I got what I want with

```
key2 <- json %>% enter_object("key2")
attributes(key2)$JSON %>% unlist() %>% paste0(collapse = ";")
```

but as I don't have unique keys I can't join it to the rest of my data and I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you got something working! In case anyone else happens upon this question, there are definitely many ways to accomplish this task!

One is to use `tidyjson` to gather the data into a tall structure, then summarize:

```r
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)

json <- "{\"key1\":\"test\",\"key2\":[\"abc\",\"def\"]}"
myj <- tidyjson::as.tbl_json(json)

myj %>% 
  # make the data tall
  spread_values(key1 = jstring(key1)) %>% 
  enter_object("key2") %>% 
  gather_array("idx") %>% 
  append_values_string("key2") %>%
  # now summarize
  group_by(key1) %>%
  summarize(key2 = paste(key2, collapse = ";"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   key1  key2   
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 test  abc;def
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Another way is to grab the json data directly with `json_get_column()` and mutate that:

```r
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)

json <- "{\"key1\":\"test\",\"key2\":[\"abc\",\"def\"]}"
myj <- tidyjson::as.tbl_json(json)

myj %>% 
  spread_values(key1 = jstring(key1)) %>%
  enter_object("key2") %>%
  json_get_column("array") %>%
  mutate(key2 = purrr::map_chr(array, ~ paste(.x, collapse = ";"))) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% # drop tbl_json structure
  select(key1, key2)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   key1  key2   
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 test  abc;def
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>